# eveluate integral,along curve $C:r=3u^2i+uj+2u^3k$.

Tags: integration

if $F=x^2.y^3i+yz^2j+zx^2$, eveluate integral $F.dr$ along the curve  $C:r=3u^2i+uj+2u^3k$ between $A(3,-1,-2)$ and $B(3,1,2)$

my practices.

integration F(r(u)).r(u)'.du
x=3u^2
y=u
z=2u^3

r(u)'=$6ui+j+6u^2k$
write x,y,x in equation.
part of ı dont understand ,
how can ı use $A(3,-1,-2)$ and $B(3,1,2)$ point ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the points, you can figure out that $u$ is going from $-1$ to $1$.

Then, you can integrate $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}F(r(u)) \bullet r'(u)\,du$.

Keep in mind, since you're using the dot-product, you have $F(r(u))=(3u^2)^2(u^2)\vec{i}+u(2u^3)^2\vec{j}+(2u^3)(3u^2)^2\vec{k}$ and $r'(u)=6u\vec{i}+\vec{j}+6u^2\vec{k}$

Comment: we can say ,y = u and 
 y (1,-1) ?

Comment: well, not necessarily $y=u$

Comment: yes ,dot-product = skalar
but ı dont understand last part ? .1,-1 :/

Comment: clock a.m 5.14,ı have to sleep :),ı hope you answer my question,thank you so much :)